# Iterating with sscanf

Tags: c, getline, scanf

I do not know much about the sscanf function, but what I am trying to do is iterate through a line of integers. Given the variable

```
    char *lineOfInts
```

I have made this the line that registers the users input. I am able to get the input fine, but when I try to use sscanf, I want to iterate through every int. I know that I can account through all the ints if i know how many ints there will be before hand like this..

```
   sscanf(lineOfInts, "%d %d %d..etc", &i, &j, &k...)
```

but what if I don't know how many integers a user will input? How can I account for all of the integers with just one variable? like

```
   sscanf(lineOfInts, "%d", &temp);
   //modifying int
   // jump to next int and repeat
```

thanks!

Comment: There is a other way to do this .. You want `sscanf() ` only?

Comment: You should have RTFM before asking here.

Comment: Yeah I only want to use sscanf(). Also, what is RTFM?

Comment: STFW for [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM).

Comment: I see. Well I have read the manual and I am still confused, shocker. Which is why I am posting here. No need to plague my post with your sour attitude

Comment: But my answer pointed you to the two features of `sscanf` that are useful to you...

Comment: I'm not supposed to be using one of the functions you mentioned, and I just wanted some clarity on sscanf, but I do appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  const char * str = "10 202 3215 1";
  int i = 0;
  unsigned int count = 0, tmp = 0;
  printf("%s\n", str);
  while (sscanf(&str[count], "%d %n", &i, &tmp) != EOF) {
    count += tmp;
    printf("number %d\n", i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably better with `"%d %n"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strtol` in a loop until you don't find the `NUL` character, if you need to store those numbers use an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NUMBERS 10

int main(void) 
{
    char *str = "12 45 16 789 99";
    char *end = str;
    int numbers[MAX_NUMBERS];
    int i, count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBERS; i++) {
        numbers[i] = (int)strtol(end, &end, 10);
        count++;
        if (*end == '\0') break;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read much more about [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) and [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html)

Notice that `sscanf` returns the number of scanned elements and accepts the `%n` conversion specifier (for the number of consumed `char`-s). Both are extremely useful in your case. And `strtol` manages the end pointer.

So you could use that in a loop...

Answer (score 0):

Use `"%n"` to record the count of characters scanned.

```
char *lineOfInts;

char *p = lineOfInts;
while (*p) {
  int n;
  int number;
  if (sscanf(p, "%d %n", &number, &n) == 0) {
    // non-numeric input
    break;
  }
  p += n;
  printf("Number: %d\n", number);
}
```